# How to get multiple modals on same page to work

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get multiple modals to work on the same page and am having some trouble.

Essentially, I want to know is, why does this work:

```
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item">
    1
    <button class="open">open</button>
    <div class="modal hide">
      <button class="close">close</button>
      one
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    2
    <button class="open">open</button>
    <div class="modal hide">
      <button class="close">close</button>
      two
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    3
    <button class="open">open</button>
    <div class="modal hide">
      <button class="close">close</button>
      three
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

-

```
var open = document.querySelectorAll( '.open' );

for ( y=0; y<open.length; y++ ) {
    open[y].addEventListener( 'click', function() {

        var modal = this.parentNode.querySelector( '.modal' );
        modal.classList.remove( 'hide' );
    });
}


var close = document.querySelectorAll( '.close' );

for ( x=0; x<close.length; x++ ) {
    close[x].addEventListener( 'click', function() {
        this.parentNode.classList.add( 'hide' );
    });
}
```

But this doesn't:
(notice the lack of the `button.open`, now the "open" event is binded to `li.item`... opening still works, but closing does not)

```
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item">
    1
    <div class="modal hide">
      <button class="close">close</button>
      one
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    2
    <div class="modal hide">
      <button class="close">close</button>
      two
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    3
    <div class="modal hide">
      <button class="close">close</button>
      three
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

-

```
var item = document.querySelectorAll( '.item' );

for ( i=0; i<item.length; i++ ) {
    item[i].addEventListener( 'click', function() {

        var modal = this.querySelector( '.modal' );
        modal.classList.remove( 'hide' );
    });
}

var close = document.querySelectorAll( '.close' );

for ( x=0; x<close.length; x++ ) {
    close[x].addEventListener( 'click', function() {
        this.parentNode.classList.add( 'hide' );
    });
}
```

Comment: What u r trying to do exactly??? Explain?

Comment: how can e.target.matches('.close') ?

Comment: I have reformulated my question. Hopefully it is clearer now. @krishnar

Comment: @BlackKnight  So basically you want to open modal when open button clicked and close it when close button clicked right?

Comment: @krishnar well actually... exactly as you described it I've already got working. what I actually want, is the second variation, where there isn't any open button, just the close button. and the opening is done by just clicking the list item, and then the closing withe the close button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var item = document.querySelectorAll( 'li' );

for ( i=0; i<item.length; i++ ) {
    item[i].addEventListener( 'click', function() { 
      // this.parent will give li and then find modal
      var modal = this.querySelector('.modal')
      modal.classList.remove("hide");
    });
}

var close = document.querySelectorAll( '.close' );

for ( x=0; x<close.length; x++ ) {
    close[x].addEventListener( 'click', function(e) {
      // this.parentNode will give directly modal
      
      var modal = this.parentNode
      modal.classList.add("hide");
      // Stop child to parent bubbling
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
}
```

```css
.hide{
   display: none;
}

li{
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item">
    1(click to open)
    <button class="open">open</button>
    <div class="modal hide">
      <button class="close">close</button>
      one
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    2(click to open)
    <button class="open">open</button>
    <div class="modal hide">
      <button class="close">close</button>
      two
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    3(click to open)
    <button class="open">open</button>
    <div class="modal hide">
      <button class="close">close</button>
      three
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. I have reformulated my question to make it clearer. I have used your code as an example :)

Comment: @BlackKnight Check now.I updated snippet and I think u are expecting to hide and show modal based on button open and close.

Comment: So, I've already got it to work like that. What I want is the second variation, where there is no open button, and the opening is done by just clicking the list item itself (the closing is still done with the close button though). I've omitted the CSS for brevity.

Comment: @BlackKnight check now.This is what ur looking for

Comment: Without the open button, opening the modal by clicking on the list item works, but the close button stops working. That's what's getting me confused...

Comment: @BlackKnight  u can open with li or open button and close it with close button.

Comment: awesome! that's it! is it just the `e.stopPropagation();` that made it work?

Comment: @BlackKnight  If u mention question properly you would have got solution early.But good! u got solution.  Upvote and accept answer if my solution found useful to u.